# Poor boy, rebel, against the state climbing on buildings etc

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

The storyline is about a boy from a poor part of the state, which is poisoning and harassing them.

He fought against them by stealing things like medicines and food. They send the girl of his age, a soldier, to find him and arrest him but she falls in love with him. I think her name is Jun Paris and his name is something like Day or Dan. They climb on buildings, fight police etc.

The first book is fighting against the police and he was arrested. In another book there was more fighting against the army. In the third book the government was destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [*Legend*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_(Lu_novel))

This novel was published in 2013 by Marie Lu.
The names of the protagonists match nearly perfectly: June Iparis and Daniel “Day” Altan Wing. According to Wikipedia, June is a soldier, as mentioned in the question:

> June Iparis, a fifteen-year-old prodigy who scored a perfect 1500 on
> her Trial, the Republic's mandatory test system. Born into an elite
> Republic family, her parents were mysteriously killed in a car crash,
> leaving Metias, her older brother, to care for her.

By contrast, Day is a criminal:

> Daniel “Day” Altan Wing, a fifteen-year-old rebellious criminal born in the slums of the
> Republic. Day is the Republic’s most-wanted criminal and the prime
> suspect of Metias’s murder.

Indeed, he steals medicine and food, as mentioned in the question:

> He once torched a whole squadron of fighter jets on an empty airfield
> in the middle of the night and has on two occasions grounded airships
> by crippling their engines. He once vandalized the side of a military
> building. He’s stolen money, food, and goods. But he doesn’t set
> roadside bombs. He doesn’t shoot soldiers. He doesn’t attempt
> assassinations. He doesn’t kill.
>
> <sub>*Legend*</sub>

There are indeed two other books in the series: *Prodigy* and *Champion*.

This may be the same book as [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96803/51379).

Comment: It is indeed the same book, series.

Comment: @Bookeater - True. We don’t dupe [tag:story-identification] questions until they both have accepted answers, though (which the other one does not - thus why I wrote an answer for this one).